# Removing the first 3 characters from a string

Tags: java, string

What is the most efficient way to remove the first 3 characters of a string?

For example:

```
'apple' change to 'le'  
'a cat' change to 'at'  
' a b c'change to 'b c'
```

Comment: You should learn basics of [String in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, removing first character of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503656/in-java-removing-first-character-of-a-string)

Comment: Please search SO before asking questions.  Such a basic question has definitely been asked before.

Comment: Yet somehow it still got 150+ upvotes and the answer 345+.  Great question!

Comment: @HarryJoy you should learn sharing what you know.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Just use substring: `"apple".substring(3);` will return `le`

Answer (score 11):

Use the [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method of the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class :

```
String removeCurrency=amount.getText().toString().substring(3);
```