# How can I remove the leading two digits from year in Date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

How can I remove the leading two digits from the year in the format `08/07/2018` in JavaScript? I just want to display 08/07/18.

Comment: Same way you would with a string (convert to string first, then convert back to number). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131876/5079258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)**.

```js
var dateStr = '19/02/2008';
var output = dateStr.slice(0, 6) + dateStr.slice(8);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: And why is that essential information not mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Kahn, use `('' + d).slice(8);` instead.

Comment: it will return just 08. But I want 19/02/08

Comment: @Kahn, use `('' + d).slice(0, 6) + ('' + d).slice(8);`

Comment: @Kahn, I have updated my answer for yor updated question.

Answer (score 1):

If its a string you could do "1990".substr(2) else you get the year from date object and do the same thing.

Also please always share your solution always. It would be really appreciated if you share what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to remove the first two digits:

```
var myString = "1990";
var newString = myString.substr(2);

//output: 
//myString = 90
```