# Method to print a char array in reverse order using recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Hi i am trying to create a method to print a char array in reverse order using recursion?

This is what i have done so far:-

```
public class StringReverseOnCharArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverseRecursively(new char[]{'a','b','c'});
    }

    private static void reverseRecursively(char[] myCharArr)
    {
        System.out.println(myCharArr[myCharArr.length-1]);
        char [] temp=
                // what next??

        reverseRecursively(temp);
    }

}
```

I think a temp char array will do but what should i do to remove the last element from the original char array and create a temp? Or is there and other way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java ?

Comment: Recursion isn't an appropriate technique for this.

Comment: You could also add a parameter to your method which will hold the current value of the index. Then decrement the index at each call and stop the recursion when the index is 0.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I expect it is homework

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Its an assignment question actually, so i have to do this using recursion :(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, and m stuck here

Comment: @Aquillo But i need to use recursion

Comment: @ZouZou hmm seems like a good option, but just thinking if i could do it without an additional param

Comment: Why not try something simple such as add the first character to a string and return the string,  the remove it as you call the function again. Just go with some approach and show you have tried

Comment: @Aquillo Yeah, something like that, so..

Comment: @JamesBlack so you are saying to have another method right? But i want this to be done in the same method.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503656/in-java-removing-first-character-of-a-string for removing a character and charAt to get the first letter, and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

I think I misunderstood. If you *have* to use the function as declared and just fill in the `temp` bit, and you just have to **output** the array in reverse order (not actually change its contents), then it's simple: Just make `temp` a copy of `length - 1` characters of the array (perhaps using `System.arraycopy`) and pass the new, shorter array into the function. Don't do that if the array you receive is only one character long; that's your recursion termination condition (you always have to have something that stops the recursion, it should be one of the first things you think about when looking at doing something recursively).

---

**Original answer**:

It seems to me that an assignment telling you to use the wrong technique for a problem isn't a very useful assignment. There are all kinds of appropriate teaching exercises for recursion; this isn't one of them.

But let's look at the assignment:

The goal of recursion is basically to repeated do something, on a different part of the problem, until you're done with the problem as a whole. The better example would be looping through a tree structure.

So looking at this problem, your goal is to swap characters in an array until the array has been reversed. What's the thing that repeats here? Swapping characters.

So I'd probably do it by having an index I pass into the function, and have the function swap the character at that index with the character at the `length - index` location (e.g., swap the first and last, then the second and second-to-last, etc.). Then have it call itself with `index + 1`.

All recursion fundamentally must have a "stop" condition: The point at which the function no longer calls itself. In your case, that would be `index >= length_of_array / 2`.

Note that I haven't posted code. Writing the code is the purpose of having assignments, of doing the course; it's an important part of learning.

Comment: Yeah seems like this was to trick me, so reading your answer makes me brave enough to challenge the Questioner if he denies to add another param to the method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [`System.arraycopy`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.

```
private static void reverseRecursively(char[] myCharArr, int next) {
    if (next >= myCharArr.length)
        return;

    // use recusion BEFORE printing in order to print in reversed order
    reverseRecursively(myCharArr, next+1); 
    System.out.println(myCharArr[next]);
}
```

First call to the method should use 0 for the "next" index:

```
    reverseRecursively(myCharArr, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this i gr8 solution i can use if i can add a parameter

Comment: If you are not allowed to add a parameter, you would need to create a new array without the value you are printing, and then pass the new array. It consumes much more memory (and it takes more code to do so), but I guess efficiency is the last thing this exercise is about.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out this isn´t normaly be done recursive. So this solutions is not nice, but it works:

```
public class StringReverseOnCharArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverseRecursively(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' });
    }

    private static void reverseRecursively(char[] myCharArr) {
        if (myCharArr.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(myCharArr[myCharArr.length - 1]);
            char[] temp = new char[myCharArr.length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = myCharArr[i];
            }

            reverseRecursively(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to create a new array to make it recursive. Just pass the index of the character to print in the array, and call the method recursively by subtracting 1 to this index. That would at least keep it O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: So in the end i will have to loop through :)

Comment: No. You start by calling the method with the array and length - 1 as arguments. The method prints the char at the given index, and then calls itself with the array and index - 1 as argument, untile index is < 0.

Comment: @user3263540: No. There's no need for the loop if you're using recursion. Looping would be the right way to solve the problem, but if you're using recursion, you *don't* want a loop.

Comment: @JBNizet You´re right but i´ve tried not to alter the code from the question in any way. Just adding the missing parts...

Comment: @Frank Thanks, for the answer.. But after discussing with you guys seems like i need to put a question in front of the Questioner.. If he denies to add a new param.. Else case i will put on the loop you gave :)

Answer (score 0):

The Time Complexity of this will be O(n) and the space complexity will be O(1)

```
def revStr(a,b,str):
  if(a-b>len(str)):
    return str

  else:
    str[a],str[b]=str[b],str[a] #Pythons way of replacing characters
    return revStr(a+1,b-1,str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution does not take a new argument and no need to create a new Char array.

```
class Solution {
int n=0;
public void reverseString(char[] c) {
    if (n>(c.length-1)/2) 
        return;
    
        char t = c[n];
        c[n] = c[c.length-n-1];
        c[c.length-n-1] = t;
        n++;
        reverseString(c);
}
```

}