# Android string JSON data parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a string with this data:

```
mystring_json = "[{"id":"a373e3e15bac1eeb001785b40a219d","dataInserimento":"2016-09-15 09:30:14","dataPubblicazione":"2016-09-15 09:29:00"},{"id":"4b2444b7b737c8d64e7d60c6515217","dataInserimento":"2016-09-15 08:32:04","dataPubblicazione":"2016-09-15 08:28:00"}...]";
```

I have a class Poi:

```
public class Poi {
    public String id;
    private String dataInserimento;
    private String dataPubblicazione;
}
```

I create a 'Poi' list:

```
List<Poi> ppp = new ArrayList<>();
```

**I have to put my_string_json data to 'ppp' list.**

How can i do this?
I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: Are You asking for json parsing

Comment: you have to parse either manually or using gson

Comment: @Donato Micele plz try this ref: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Comment: Before Parsing Remove " refer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503656/in-java-removing-first-character-of-a-string.
Then Parse Your data

Comment: just search any json parsing tutorial for android simple

Comment: you can do this easily with gson.

Comment: Stop you are in wrong direction. Go through this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZpv6W3Lflo  . Necessary links are provided below the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer because I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

You can use gson library, so in order to parse you should do the following:

First, create the following class:

```
public class ArticleContainer {
    private List<Poi> lstPoi;
}
```

Then:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
PoiResponse poiResponse = gson.fromJson(myString_json, PoiResponse.class);
List<Poi> ppp = poiResponse.getPoi();
```

In order to compile you need to add this line to your module's build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

For more information [gson README](https://github.com/google/gson) and [Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551242/parsing-a-complex-json-object-using-gson-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna learn JSON Parsing refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Parse mystring_json and with the help of either handler class you can add it to your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
try{
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(mystring_json);
List<Poi> ppp = new Arraylist<>();
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
Poi objj= new Poi();
JSONObject jObj= arr.getJSONObject(i);
objj.setId(jObj.getString("id"));
.
.
.

// at last add 
ppp.add(objj);
}
}Catch(JSONException e){
e.printstacktrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

in your dependency section of app.gradle file. And after that, at the time of parsing

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
PoiResponse obj = gson.fromJson(data, PoiResponse.class);
List<Poi> ppp = obj.mystring_json;
```

You have to create one more class, like

```
public class PoiResponse {
  public ArrayList<Poi> mystring_json;
}
```

above **data** is your String response from server.